# Не правильно выводится переменная в C#

Tags: c#, массивы, visual-studio, случайные-числа, c#-7.0

Не правильно выводиться переменная. Ошибки не появляются.Переменная должна выводить элемент списка на экран.[image: код с выводом]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Вы сами себе злобный буратино. В C# не пишут так, как вы, ибо C# это строго типизированный язык, где вы не должны вообще хотеть засунуть все в что-то одно. Напишите конкретный тип коллекции, а не `object`, а затем, понимая что там у вас коллекция, подумайте что должно выводить программа на экран? По умолчанию `коллекция.ToString()` (а именно это делает `WriteLine()` выдаст вам тип данной коллекции, если хотите вывести элементы, то это и делайте, например `string.Join(...)`. Ну а если вам надо вывести один объект, не присваивайте это коллекции, вынесите в отдельную переменную и ее используйте.

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно выводит. Переменная a - это массив объектов. Функция Console.WriteLine(a) эквивалентна Console.WriteLine(a.ToString()), что выводит название типа переменной а не её содержание. Используйте

Console.WriteLine(a[n]), где n - номер элемента массива.

Comment: WiteLine? может быть W**r**iteLine?

Answer (score 0):

`object` можно использовать только если вы понимаете, зачем вы это делаете. Вот пример более нормального кода:

```cs
var rnd = new Random();
var arr = new List<string> { "0", "1", "a", "b" };
var n = rnd.Next(arr.Count);
Console.WriteLine(arr[n]);
```

Суть:

- список типизированный (элементы `string`, а не `object`)
- для хранения случайного индекса элемента используется отдельная переменная
- сам элемент для печати берётся по индексу из списка